# Using SQLite Select function

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database and all works fine. But How I can get out last five rows, which one's column value is for example 1.

The select and insert function have synchronized function, so the reading and inserting doesn't happen same time. There has more than 300 hundreds rows, but I only need get cursor object last 5 rows (so I get all columns in one row) which one's column value is 1.

Thanks for any helps!

Comment: what? Sorry but I don't get your problem. You want 5 rows? Use limit 5. But what is the deal with the column value 1? I don' get it...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *                     -- list of the columns you want
  FROM table
 WHERE column1 = 1           -- rows with column1 = 1
 ORDER BY (ordering columns) -- columns by which you want to order
 LIMIT 5                     -- and get the last 5
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I thinks that works fine. My use case is following:

Comment: So thanks for help, I get it now and also I will read documentation for this kind problems next time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select the first five rows which have all have a certain column with a value of one. If so, using a `WHERE` and `LIMIT` statement should help:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE the_column = 1 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: @user760503 What do you mean? The `LIMIT 5` selects the last five rows. If you need them ordered by a certain column (as manji has in his answer) use `ORDER BY`. (Also, remember to to click to accept the answer that satisfies you - if that happens, lol).

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the method `database.query();`
as follows:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(false, TABLE,new String[] {COLUMNS_TO_SELECT},"YOUR_WHERE_CLAUSE", null, null, null, null /*ORDER BY*/, "5"/*YOUR_LIMIT*/);
```

Have a look at [**Documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)